# multiple gRPC servers and a unified API

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Suppose we have multiple gRPC servers that provides different services. We would like to have one unified API in the client side that acts like a proxy (i.e a translator) that calls appropriate function based on the given request. What do you suggest for implementing of such idea? Should I have a  gRPC proxy server (in the client side) that acts as a gRPC server and a client at  the same time?

Comment: If you're talking about translating REST or JSON RPC HTTP requests into GRPC, have a look at GRPC gateway https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway

Comment: No I mean translating gRPC to gRPC

Comment: Please provide more information about your architecture and the reasons why one layer of your backend should duplicate another one (if I understood you correctly).

Comment: @VitalyIsaev  Suppose we have multiple gRPC APIs that each designed for a specific purpose. I want to expose a unified API on top of those gRPC APIs.

Comment: Which kind of task this proxy layer will be responsible for? However, I think that if you really need it, you should write code generator, that will create a server-client transmit per every Request. In fact client will just reuse data structures coming into server.

Comment: I think the proxy should act as a server and client at the same time. It should act as a server for the clients and act as a client for underlying servers. The functions in the proxy are responsible to call an appropriate function according to the given message.

Comment: @AdibRastegarnia did you succeed in creating such as proxy? I have a similar use case and haven't found a way to do so yet since the proxy gRPC server must first register each of the backend services. My only though of a workaround currently would be to make a very low-level HTTP2 proxy that parses the service and rpc names from the incoming payload, and then relay the raw request to the appropriate backend server